# Data structure recommendations for exercise

Tags: python, data-structures

As a part of Data Structure course my teacher gave me an extra exercise which is a little bit more difficult and challenging.
I`ve tried to find out the Data Structure I need to use for this problem and I dont have any idea, also I want to try to code it by myself out of the exercise to improve my python skills.

About the exercise:
1. I have a text file with logs which looks like that:

```
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:39, 4, xxxx, username, “Initialization of the system, and loading
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 100, xxxx, username, “Open Connection”
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 100, xxxx, username, “Close Connection, and reboot”
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 6, xxxx, New User, We created the user in the systems
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:41, 3, xxxx, User logged in, User username logged in
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:39, 4, xxxx, username, “Initialization of the system”
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 6, xxxx, New User, We created the user in the systems
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:41, 3, xxxx, User logged in, User username logged in
```

there are 2 types of logs, M is Master and S is Slave.
I need a data structure which will be able to split each row and grab it into a specific column.
i.e M-1 columns will be :

```
M, 1, Datetime, Error Level, DeviceId, UserId, Message
```

but S-1 columns will be :

```
S, 1, Datetime, Error Level, DeviceId, Action, Message
```

Note : as you can see there is Action in S,1 but not UserId.

What I need to be able to do at the end is to enter in the command line the columns that I want to stdout and a condition (i.e. Error Level > 50).

What I tought about was Dictionary, but by this way I won't be able to support unlimited number of versions (if its possible, please explain me how).

Thanks!

Comment: Make 2 different Classes for `Master` and `Slave` and store them as a list of classes in a dictionary with key as `{'master': [list of master classes.....], 'slave': [list of slave classes.....]}`

Comment: Wouldn't a simple list of tuples (one tuple per row) suffice? Or, if you want to be more verbose, a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @Nitin I got you , but by this way I will have to declare every version, and I want it to support unlimited versions, so how can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "support unlimited number of versions"? Versions of what?

Comment: @Goyo Version like m-2 , m-3 and so on also with ‘s’

Comment: The version is the second element in the tuple, then. What is the problem?

Comment: @Ronald Aaronson What I had to do in this one is just to tell what’s the Data Structure I need to use, I want to continue by coding for myself, and btw I did offer my solution

Comment: @Goyo can you give an example for that so I can understand better?

Comment: How about you try to solve the problem using tuples, lists or dictionaries (any of them will do) and then ask a question when you have a specific problem?

Comment: If "what you had to do is just tell what's the Data Structure you need to use", that is essentially your homework assignment. You made a choice but did not attempt to verify whether it was a viable one by then using that data structure in an actual coded solution but proceeded to ask for our solution. So I would not give you much credit for your "work".  And, BTW, some of your Slave strings seems to be missing DeviceId fields.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson thats the point of the exercise, Slave doesnt have the same columns as Master..

Comment: `S, 1, Datetime, Error Level, DeviceId, Action, Message` I count **7** columns for this and I count **7** for `M, 1, Datetime, Error Level, DeviceId, UserId, Message`. And how many columns do you see in: `S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:41, 3, User logged in, User username logged in`?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson you are currect, its missing the deviceId, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use a `namedtuple` class from the `collections` package to hold each parsed item since it allows you to access each field by an index number and also by name. Moreover, new `namedtuple` classes can be dynamically created rather easily by passing a list of column names.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Master = namedtuple('Master', ['Type', 'N', 'Datetime', 'ErrorLevel', 'DeviceId', 'UserName', 'Message'])
Slave = namedtuple('Slave', ['Type', 'N', 'Datetime', 'ErrorLevel', 'DeviceId', 'Action', 'Message'])

n_cols = 7

logfileasstring = """
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:39, 4, xxxx, username, “Initialization of the system, and loading
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 100, xxxx, username, “Open Connection”
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 100, xxxx, username, “Close Connection, and reboot”
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 6, xxxx, New User, We created the user in the systems
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:41, 3, xxxx, User logged in, User username logged in
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:39, 4, xxxx, username, “Initialization of the system”
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 6, xxxx, New User, We created the user in the systems
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:41, 3, xxxx, User logged in, User username logged in"""


master_list = []
slave_list = []

for r in logfileasstring.splitlines(False):
    if not r:
        continue
    values = [value.strip() for value in r.split(',', n_cols - 1)]
    if r[0] == 'M':
        master_list.append(Master(*values))
    else:
        slave_list.append(Slave(*values))


print(master_list[0][6]) # by index
print(master_list[0].Message) # by column name if name known in advance
column_name = 'Message'
print(master_list[0].__getattribute__(column_name)) # by column name if name not known in advance
```

[Run demo](http://ideone.com/a1og8h)

Comment: @RolandAaronson I really appreciate your explanation! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

does this help:

```
logfileasstring = """
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:39, 4, xxxx, username, “Initialization of the system, and loading
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 100, xxxx, username, “Open Connection”
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 100, xxxx, username, “Close Connection, and reboot”
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 6, xxxx, New User, We created the user in the systems
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:41, 3, xxxx, User logged in, User username logged in
M, 1, 14/08/2019 11:39, 4, xxxx, username, “Initialization of the system”
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:40, 6, New User, We created the user in the systems
S, 1, 14/08/2019 11:41, 3, User logged in, User username logged in"""
listoflist = [[v.strip() for v in r.split(",", maxsplit=6)]
               for r in logfileasstring.splitlines(keepends=False) 
               if r]

grouped = {("M", "1"): [], ("S", "1"): []}
for row in listoflist:
    datasets_for = grouped[row[0], row[1]]
    datasets_for.append(row[2:])


# must be set by script
fields = [0, 1, 2]
for k in grouped:
    print(k, "::")
    for row in grouped[k]:
        print("  -", [row[f] for f in fields])
```

Comment: @jgsedi Thats an idea but I can't work with it cuz I will need to make a method which prints only selected columns, for this I will have to declaire columns befor.

Comment: yes but there must be an indicator for the columns or at least the number of a column to detect the column to be printed. If you will do that in a script (cli) like: `script --cols 0,3,4 logfile` so the code must only changed in the last part - to select the appropriate fields of the row. **i changed my code above**.

Comment: @jgsedi Yes I got you by your result you access the columns by the index inside the array, I want to access it by name and not by index, I.e. stdin for columns filter will be UserId

Comment: Also, when you split on `','`, won't you be splitting up unintentionally `“Close Connection, and reboot”`?

Comment: no. i prevent splitting the last entry with `split(",", maxsplit=6)`. so the last split is right before the log text

Comment: as i mentioned @R_L: if you want to select columns by name you have to name the columns first.